# How to show multiple actions on a list item in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am coming from android and trying to replicate my small app to iOS. I basically have a list of things and certain actions can be taken on each thing. For example:

```
Colors
---------
Red       <fav> <delete> <edit>
Green     <fav> <delete> <edit>
...
Black     <fav> <delete> <edit>
```

Though I have not seen many apps on iOS do this. Is this doable? Or should I have an "Edit" button on top right hand which then shows these actions?

Comment: use storyboard and design your own prototype cell for a tableView with the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you describe, namely a list of editable items, the Master-Detail-Application template seems to be a good fit. Editing these items is usually done by tapping the respective item, which then brings up the detail view. A swipe gesture usually allows to delete items from a list.

Also you can have a look at the Mail app and see how it handles the e-mail list (aka items) and one email with its text, etc (aka detail view). I would suggest a similar behavior for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableView to show the list of items.

Refer this link to know about UITableView : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

In UITableView, You can create the custom cell and add your buttons (fav,delete,edit) on it.

Please refer this link as well : http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Thanks!